# HTML: Change height of <p>

Tags: html, css

How do I specify the height of the blank line that inserting a `<p>` creates?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your style sheet, or style sheet section, define this: (example)

```
p {  margin-top: 0.6em; margin-bottom: 0em; }
```

You can also specify it in the individual tag `<p style="margin-top:.....">`

Answer (score 7):

Use CSS to mark the line height for something. E.g.:

```
p{
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

That is for lines of text. To make a margin (The room between the

and everything else) define it like this.

```
  p{
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
   }
```

That will adjust the blank space in each direction (accordingly).

Comment: I think he wants to change the margin. The margin is what adds the space below the `<p>` tag.

Comment: Oh and when it comes to `line-height`, I find it good practice to define it without a unit, like so: `line-height: 1.4;` That makes it always relative to the current font size (even when cascading, unlike `1.4em`.)

Comment: Updated with your suggestions Blixt

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to note that changing the margin of a single line doesn't help, so one may not see the effects in the browser as quickly as they expect. For example:

```
<p style="margin-bottom:50px">line 50</p>
<p style="margin-top:100px">line 100</p>
```

results in the margin of 100 px between these lines. 50px margin overlaps the bigger one and the bigger value is the actual margin. Reducing bottom margin of the first line doesn't change anything, as well as increasing it to the value <=100px. So **this works differently than line spacing *before* and *after* in text editor**.

Tested in Firefox with Firebug, where yellow area denotes margins.

Answer (score 0):

change the top and bottom margin heights.