# How to reduce the space between <p> tags?

Tags: html, css

I have a page that I'm converting to PDF. This page contains a number of paragraphs and they don't all fit onto a single page. If I could reduce the spacing between the `<p>` tags, this would help fit more. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: How are you converting them to PDF?

Comment: @deceze: two examples: Ubuntu can "print" anything to PDF out of the box. Windows can "print" to PDF with Acrobat installed (costs a few hundred).

Comment: @Delan And OS X can too, fine. Since this is a programming site though I was assuming the OP does it programmatically. CSS may not have anything to do with the solution then.

Comment: @deceze, We're using a (crap) system called Corda Highwire. You pass it a URL to your page and it'll generate a PDF representation of it. The crappy thing about it is that it appears the rendering engine was based on IE6 standards so you have to hack the hell out of your standard HTML to get it to resemble your content. There's another solution called PrinceXML that I've looked into which looks pretty good, but we're locked into Corda so this is what I'm stuck with.

Comment: I'll do my best to avoid Corda then. Thanks for the warning. :o)

Comment: @Delan Don't pay to have the monopolistic version when you can have free ones - http://www.cutepdf.com/

Comment: @sr pt: that's why I use Ubuntu :P

Comment: There is a similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/1174020/772981](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1174020/772981)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

use css :

```
p { margin:0 }
```

Try this wonderful plugin http://www.getfirebug.com :)

**EDIT**: Firebug is now closed as a project, it was migrated to https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer

Comment: Thanks y_nk, I use firebug when I can but it isn't much help when working with PDF!!

Comment: But Dave, if you pass it a URL to your page you can use the URL to check how the page renders. :)

Comment: True sr pt, but the PDF doesn't get rendered the exact same as what we see in the browser. I do use the IE Developer Toolbar sometimes to get an insight into the structure of the HTML but this PDF generator we use is a very untame beast.

Answer (score 11):

As shown above, the **problem** is the margin preceding the `<p>` tag in rendering time.
Not an elegant solution but effective would be to decrease the top margin.

```
p { margin-top: -20px; }
```

Answer (score 7):

The CSS `margin` property can be used to affect all paragraphs:

```
p {
  margin: XXXem;
}
```

Replace `XXX` with your desired value; for no space at all use:

```
p {
  margin: 0em;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<style type="text/css">
 p {margin-bottom: -1em;  margin-top: 0em;} 
</style>
```

This completely worked for me. Paragraphs were right below each other. When I used 0em for both the margins, there was still some space left in between the lines. I went for Developer tools in my browser, tried with -1em and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I have found this to work to give more book style paragraphs:

```css
p.firstpar {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-indent: 2em;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
p.nextpar {
  margin-top: -1em;
  text-indent: 2em;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

using the `em` ("M") unit, rather than `px` unit, it makes the style independent of the font-size. Padding goes in that order: top, right, bottom, left.

Answer (score 3):

A more real-world example:

```
p { margin: 10px 0;}
```

Comment: this worked quite well too, it in fact worked better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest to set padding and margin to 0.

If this does not solve your problem you can try playing with line-height even if not reccomended.

Comment: It's `margin` only. `p` tags don't use `padding` for their default spacing, and `line-height` is spacing between lines (which if decreased will cause lines to overlap.

Comment: Without having access to the actual source I cannot assure that line-height wouldn't help, even if, as stated, it's not recommended.

Padding would not change space between two paragraphs but nonetheless, if setted to a value greater than 0 it will VISUALLY ends in a greater space between the twos.

Thanks for the note! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

If this doesn't work, try

```
line-height: normal;
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392584/remove-spacing-between-p) to add in line styling to the '<p'> I needed to remove the space from.

```
<p style="margin : 0; padding-top:0;">Remove space</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce space between paragraphs. If you are using blogger, you'd go to template, 'customize' then find 'add css' and paste this:
p {margin:.7em 0 .7em 0} /*Reduces space between

from full line to approx. 1/2 line */
If you are just tagging your webpage, that's still what you would use, just put it into your css file(s).

I was an sgml template designer in the late 70s/early 80s and all this tagging is just a dtd within sgml (even if they are now trying to say that html5/css3 is 'not', YES IT STILL IS.) `:)`

You can find all this basic info at w3schools too you know. Really if you are learning how to do layout using tagging or even javascript, etc. you should start with w3schools. Some people say it is 'not always' right, but folks, I've been in IT since 1960 (age 12) and w3schools is best for beginners. Are some things wrong there? Ah, I dunno, I haven't found any mistake, although sometimes if you are a beginner you might need to read two viewpoints to truly grasp the sense of something. But do remember that you are NOT programming when you code a webpage, you are simply doing layout work. (Yell all you want folks, that's the truth of it.)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me but this does -- Use `<P style='line-height: 8px;'>` to replace `<p>` wherever needed (or put it in the style tag like `<style>P {line-height: 8px;}</style>` to affect all `<p>` tags). I realise Mauro says this, but if someone comes here for help, I expect they would want to see an example.

Comment: What ... marked this down without a comment? I don't try to help others for my health you know..

Answer (score 0):

Setting both margin-bottom and margin-top to 0em will remove a space between paragraphs:

```
<style type="text/css">
p {margin-bottom: 0em; margin-top: 0em;}
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're converting an HTML doc into a PDF page, but the page spills onto two pages, try reducing the font size. Of course you can also decrease the spacing between paragraphs (with the CSS margin-top/margin-bottom styles), or even the left and right gutters with margins. But to my eye, keep things in proportion and just make the text a little smaller:

```
p { font-size: 90%; }
```

or

```
body { font-size: 9.5pt }
```

Answer (score -3):

Replace `<p> </p>` with `&nbsp;`
Add as many `&nbsp;` as needed.

I solved the same problem by this. Just sharing it.

Comment: It meant, replace <$p><$/p> with &$nbsp.. Remove $ from the tags

Comment: That's a bit of a hack though, isn't it? littering the html with &nbsp; is very frowned upon.

Comment: It serves your purpose, If you are not too keen into html & have lot of other stuffs to worry about..