# CSS to remove the spacing between the lines

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to remove the spacing between the two center align text?

HTML :

```
  <div id="content2">
       <p class="t1">Discover</p>
       <p class="t1">Discover</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #content2 {
        clear: both;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .t1 {
      font-weight: bold;    
      font-size:60px;   
      color: black;
        text-align: center;
    }

p {
    font-size : 30px;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 30px;
    line-height : 20px;
}
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/owNJRr

I'm also adapting from this thread : 
[Remove spacing between <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392584/remove-spacing-between-p)

When I increase the line height , the spacing between the `content2` and `p` also increase.

I'm looking for similar output to this :

[image]

Each time I increase the line height, it also affect the spacing of the first pharagraph `<p>` and the `content2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best you can do is to remove margin / padding from the p tag and adjust the line height.

As an example check this out https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRGzNW

Html:

```
<div id="content2">
   <p class="t1">testGg</p>
   <p class="t1">testgG</p>
   <p class="t1">testGg</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#content2 {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.t1 {
    font-weight: bold;  
    font-size:60px; 
    line-height:60px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
}
```

Comment: After adding !important on your code then it works O_o. Thanks mate for the advice . Looking to fix for firefox but i guess this would just do it.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Waiting to approve your answer, really thank for your effort. Also , a quick question. just now someone posted their answer before removing it. I saw he use to call two class in a pharagraph. Is it possible to inherit two class/id in an element?

Comment: Those comments here are a bit bad to give longer explanations. In short: Classes yes, IDs no. Check out this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp They explain it a little bit better.

Answer (score 2):

> You can use Two class for a paragraph and `margin-top` Property for it.

```css
#content2 {
 clear: both;
 overflow: auto;
}

.t1 {

  font-weight: bold;  
  font-size:60px; 
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  
}

p {
    font-size : 30px;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 30px;
    line-height : 20px;
}

.t {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="content2">
       <p class="t1">test</p>
       <p class="t1 t">test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you're the guy i'm looking for ! i saw you deleted your comment awhile ago. It's a first time i'm looking two class into a pharagraph class. I mean , you're overwritting between the pharagraph.

Comment: i cant see uploaded your image.so i guess what you want.I hope help you.

Comment: oh, it's not an image, it's actually a container called content2. So from the top of the container2 i'm setting a padding top which you suggested early. On top of that, the line between the two pharagraph is my issue.

Comment: Thank you for your post!