# Why <p> have two line breaks instead one?

Tags: css, html

I don´t understand why `<p>` tag in HTML has two line breaks instead one, can someone tell me why its like that and if its possible to fix it to one with CSS.

Two line breaks:

```html
<p>Hello World</p>my name is Yoel.
```

Compares with `<br>` one line break:

```html
Hello World
<br>my name is Yoel.
```

Comment: Related: [How to reduce the space between <p> tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787310/how-to-reduce-the-space-between-p-tags)

Comment: Try this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing isn't actually an extra line-break, but a margin.  By default `p` tags come with a small margin to help visually define them.

If you want to get rid of that you can add the following to your CSS:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ON Chrome you get default styles:

```
  p{
        display: block;
       -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    }
```

If you set them to 0 you will get the same result as br tag

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different render engines and apply different user agent stylesheets.

By default, browsers apply a `margin` to `<p>` elements.

---

You can remove the `margin-bottom` with

```
p { margin-bottom: 0;}
```

Or even better, do this:

```html
<p>Hello World
  <br>my name is Yoel.</p>
```

---

The `<br>` tag is correctly used if it is inside a `<p>` tag, it indicates a line-break in a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` is meant to be a new *paragraph*, while `<br>` is the one to use for just a *line break*.

> A paragraph (from the Ancient Greek παράγραφος paragraphos, "to write beside" or "written beside") is a self-contained unit of a discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea. A paragraph consists of one or more sentences. Though not required by the syntax of any language, paragraphs are usually an expected part of formal writing, used to organize longer prose [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph)